# Random, intermittent "argument out of range" error while parsing CSV and parsing time

Tags: ruby, date, csv, time

I'm working on a Ruby script to import some data I have in a CSV to Mixpanel and I've had a heck of a time working with dates/times. Basically, I'm to the point where I can loop through the CSV and after every some-odd rows when I try and do:

```
Time.zone = attributes["TIMEZONE"] #for instance, "America/Los_Angeles"
timestamp = attributes["CONFIRM_TIME"] #for instance, "11/1/2010 20:51:00"
timestamp = Time.zone.parse(timestamp)
```

I get:

```
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:289:in `initialize': argument out of range (ArgumentError)
        from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:289:in `new'
        from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:289:in `parse'
        from /home/action/workspace/csv-to-mixpanel/import.rb:55:in `import_user'
        from /home/action/workspace/csv-to-mixpanel/import.rb:42:in `block in perform!'
        from /home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/csv.rb:1720:in `each'
        from /home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/csv.rb:1122:in `block in foreach'
        from /home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/csv.rb:1268:in `open'
        from /home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/csv.rb:1121:in `foreach'
        from /home/action/workspace/csv-to-mixpanel/import.rb:40:in `perform!'
        from cli.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

If I catch the error, it'll keep on chugging on but throw up the error intermittently after some-odd rows (it's really random, sometimes it'll through it up for 10-20 rows at a time). So much so that I'm only getting about 1/3 of the data in to Mixpanel.

It's not the data itself - I can randomly delete rows from the CSV and it'll always crash at what appears to be the same exact spot. I've dumped the rows it's crashing on and they look exactly the same. That being said, here is a row that it is failing on:

```
email,First_name,Last_name,Source,type,MEMBER_RATING,OPTIN_TIME,OPTIN_IP,CONFIRM_TIME,CONFIRM_IP,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,GMTOFF,DSTOFF,TIMEZONE,CC,REGION,LAST_CHANGED,LEID,EUID,NOTES
brett@brettneese.com, Brett, Neese, Adult,,5,10/18/2011 15:20:15,71.23.42.75,10/18/2011,71.23.42.75,37.4055,-122.078,-8,-7,America/Los_Angeles,US,CA,11/12/2011 23:19:19,94381326,26d74c4d03,
```

(I've tried deleting the empty columns and still have problems.)

I'm out of ideas. Help?

Comment: Please give us some example rows of where it fails.

Comment: What date format is that - `dd/m/yyyy` or `mm/d/yyyy`?

Comment: @user4235730 added row example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
Time.parse('31/1/2001') # => 2001-01-31 00:00:00 -0700
Time.parse('1/31/2001') # => argument out of range (ArgumentError)
```

Why is it out of range? Because Ruby, by default tries to break a date string that matches that format into a day, month, year format, AKA `'%d/%m/%Y'`.

It's not possible to have a month number 31, at least not in this reality, so Ruby raises an exception.

Instead, using your time value and `strptime`:

```
Time.parse('18/10/2011') # => 2011-10-18 00:00:00 -0700
Time.parse('10/18/2011') # => argument out of range (ArgumentError)

Time.strptime('10/18/2011', '%m/%d/%Y' ) # => 2011-10-18 00:00:00 -0700
```

This is a situation you can't fix by trying to trap the exception. `parse` isn't smart enough to deal with this either, nor can it be made smart enough. You HAVE to know the LOCALE or the date format being sent to you.

Trying to parse without knowing means that the date you get back could very well be wrong. For instance, which format is this:

```
Time.parse('10/12/2011') # => 2011-12-10 00:00:00 -0700
```

Is it *really* October 12 or is it December 10? It kind of depends on where your data originated, which is typically set by the LOCALE OS setting of the machine that sent it. `parse` can't tell, so it does the easy thing it was told to do, and it assumes it's `'%d/%m/%Y'` format and returns that to the code, and, unless you looked carefully, you probably let the database store that.

Comment: I fixed that with `timestamp = Time.strptime(timestamp, '%m/%d/%Y %k:%M:%S' )`, but `b@email.com,Rebecca,LastName,,Adult,4,,,7/11/2011 18:31:55,00.23.42.75,34.0061,-128.00,-8,-7,America/Los_Angeles,US,CA,1/27/2012 11:52:16,396986178,39fe2984a0,` is still failing. :(

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb. Turns out I had another DateTime parser later down in the script I had to update as well. Thanks so much! :)